# Why do I get "PK" in the HTTP response when trying to download a zip file?

Tags: c++, http, curl

I'm trying to download a zip file using cURL library. This is the code I'm using to make the request :

```
const char* RestClient::user_agent = VERSION;
/** initialize authentication variable */
std::string RestClient::user_pass =  std::string();
/** Authentication Methods implementation */
void RestClient::clearAuth(){
  RestClient::user_pass.clear();}
void RestClient::setAuth(const std::string& user,const std::string& password){
  RestClient::user_pass.clear();
  RestClient::user_pass += user+":"+password;}

/** @brief HTTP GET method  @param url to query @return response struct */

RestClient::response RestClient::get(const std::string& url){
  RestClient::response ret = {};
  CURL *curl = NULL;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {
    /** set basic authentication if present*/
    if(RestClient::user_pass.length()>0){
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,RestClient::user_pass.c_str());
  }
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, RestClient::user_agent);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, RestClient::write_callback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ret);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, RestClient::header_callback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &ret);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if (res != CURLE_OK)
  {
    ret.body = "Failed to query.";
    ret.code = -1;
    return ret;
  }
  long http_code = 0;
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
  ret.code = static_cast<int>(http_code);

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  curl_global_cleanup();}
return ret;}
```

The write_callback :

```
 size_t RestClient::write_callback(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb,void *userdata)
{ RestClient::response* r;
  r = reinterpret_cast<RestClient::response*>(userdata);
  r->body.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size*nmemb);
  return (size * nmemb);}
```

The HTTP request is supposed to be :

```
http://yourserver.com/zip/<filename>.zip?downloadKind=<original|preview>&assetIds=<comma-separated asset ids>
```

When I send a request :

```
RestClient::response response = RestClient::get("http://localhost:8080/zip/tesst.zip?downloadKind=original&assetIds=60ZRK8LQ4RW8CYeZSzFmi0");
```

I get "200" as a response code and "PK" as a response body. What does "PK" mean ? and what have I done wrong?

Comment: PK is the file header for a zip archive.   So your server has decided to send the file and it expects gratitude :)

Comment: `"PK"` is the signature of a ZIP file, that is every ZIP file starts with these two characters. Are you sure there are not more bytes after those two? How are you checking the body of the answer?

Comment: But I don't get the file in Downloads folder :( what should I do to get it?

Comment: What does your write callback do? if you just want to write to a file, you can use the default function which writes to a FILE *

Comment: I'm not familiar with curl, but where do you get the "body" in your example?

Comment: @user3742053: CURL doesn't download files to a "Downloads" folder. You get the file **content**. You can do with that whatever you want: store it in a file, unzip it and store all the parts, pass it to a virusscanner first, ... CURL just handles the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the question is a bit lacking in details, but I'm going to guess.

Your `body` member variable is of type `std::string`, and that is not appropriate to store binary data. As it happens, ZIP files usually start with bytes `50 4b 03 04 xx 00` so if you interpret it as a C string, they it will end there, in the `00` byte.

You can use a `std::vector<char>` as the type of `body` instead of `std::string`. That will handle the binary data properly.

PS: Technically, `std::string` can handle embedded NUL characters, but I would bet on it. And anyway, that is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: `std:string` has no problems with NUL characters, neither in theory nor in practice. Programmers who call `std:string::string (const char*)` and expect that to magically work with embedded NUL characters do have a problem, but they'd have even bigger problems when they manually try to stuff that `const char*` in a vector.