# Error receiving json data from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send the data  in XMLHttpRequest through json, in the log I receive succesful and the data info correctly but in the php I cannot collect the data,this works with an exit() and the $data on the php file, if you take out $data it the responseText is empty, if you take out exit(), it transforms into some weird characters with ? and more nonsense, and if you use $_POST it shows array() and some weird characters again after the empty array. The js part is sent when you click on the chart.js and then it is accessed from report.php when clicking on an icon, I don't know if when accessing like this the info from the js is not arriving, as I just get a blank page. This is the js and the php:

```
onComplete: function() {
    console.log(myChart.toBase64Image());
    var imgData = myChart.toBase64Image();
    var imgRes = imgData.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            if (xhttp.status === 200) {
                console.log('successful');
             } else {
                console.log('failed');
             }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", base_url_admin+"record/reporte", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    let data = JSON.stringify({"resultChartImg": imgRes});
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

php:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// build a PHP variable from JSON sent using POST method
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);exit();
```

[Error Image of the weird characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHeMV.png)

Comment: Can you show an exaple of the wierd characters

Comment: @RiggsFolly im gonna try and put an image on the question

Comment: The `PK` at the very beginning most likely indicates that this data was ZIP-compressed, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31518541/1427878

Comment: That look like a Word Doc file. They are actually ZIP files under the covers. You cannot read a zip file like it was simple text

Comment: consider xhttp.open("POST", base_url_admin+"record/reporte?"+Date.now(), true);  to be sure the calls aren't loaded from old cache (first load)

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can I fix it?

Comment: Fix what? If the user is sending you a Microsoft Word Document, you cannot just `print_r()` it back to the users browser, IT IS A ZIP FILE

Comment: Try saving it to a file with a name like `test.docx` and then see if yo ucan read it

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats what im doing but it shows PK, etc... again in the doc file